# how to properly setup my cron job

Tags: php, cron

I am trying to set up a cron job that sends an email once in a day weekly,
from my knowledge of setting up a cron job, a cron job is supposed to execute a script.

So this is what I have done.

On my cron.php page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

   window.onload=function(){ 
    window.setTimeout(function() { document.postniid.submit(); }, 0000);
};

</script>
   <form name="postniid" id="postniid" method="post" action="cron_post.php" >

      <input name="email" type="hidden" id="inputInsured Name"  value="wolexx007@gmail.com"  />

   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have setup a form with a default email to be posted to cron_post.php, I have also made this form submit onload, because I expected that the cron would execute my cron.php page.

And my cron_post.php page:

```
<?php
$reply = $_POST['email'];



    $replysubject = "Auto-Reply: support | kblinsurance.com";
    $replyfrom = "From: noreply@kblinsurance.com\r\n";
     $replymessage .= "Testing Cron Job.\r\n\r\n";




    mail($reply,$replysubject, $replymessage, $replyfrom);  
    ?>
```

that sends the email.
It works when I test from a browser, but doesn't execute when I have set a command to execute my cron.

```
30  14  *   *   1-5 php /home5/whitech3/public_html/cron/cron.php
```

Why is this please?

Comment: `onload` is a Javascript function which is not going to be executed in a PHP script anyhow. Why don't you try to run `cron_post.php` directly with a given argument ?

Comment: please what iv i asked wrongly to warrant a thumbs down in my question, this is crazy

Comment: ok thanks i will try using an onload using php

Comment: "a cron job thats send an email once in a day weeekly" : so, daily, or weekly ? :D

Comment: once in a day thanks

Comment: For the downvotes: some people mistake "questions by people who don't have a clue" (which should not be downvoted) and "badly formed questions" (which should). It's sad.

Comment: i mean i always carefully ask my questions here, this is horrible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up client-side and server-side code. Please google for the difference.

The javascript you wrote will only be executed if the page is loaded through a browser. All your cron job is doing right now, is rendering a page with a form and some javascript code in it, but doesn't actually executes the javascript (which is the job of a browser).

Note that you don't have to rely on the POST to execute your script. In your cron.php page you can just use the cron_post.php code (and replace the `$_POST[]` with the actual email).

Comment: You do realize that by using *Please google for the difference* you are justifying all downvotes to the question as lacking research effort ;-)

Comment: How is he supposed to know that there is difference (or even the names of the concepts) if nobody tells him ? The downvoters don't take the time to at least tell him that there is a difference in a comment. It's not helpful at all.

Comment: I agree that a well-formed question like this deserves an explanation for a downvote but that's up to the individual downvoter. I guess that with the enormous amount of (bad...) questions, people could get tired of explaining the same things over and over.

Comment: Well I think it's a bit sad. Why are you taking the time to review questions if it's not to improve the quality of subsequent ones ?